# Convert "int" into "char" inside char array

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to do string manipulation. Here's my C# code :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    string input;
    string output;
    int length;

    Console.WriteLine("input = ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    length = input.Length;

    if ((input != "") || (length != 0))
    {
        Random randem = new Random();
        int i = -1; //because I do not want the first number to be replaced by the random number 
        char[] characters = input.ToCharArray();
        while (i < length)
        {
            int num = randem.Next(0, 9);
            char num1 = Convert.ToChar(num);
            i = i + 2; //so that every next character will be replaced by random number.. :D
            characters[i] = num1; //*error* here
        }
        output = new string(characters);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
     }
```

For example:

User input : `"i_love_to_eat_fish"`

Desired output : `"i2l4v1_9o5e8t7f8s2"`

notice that the only unchanged character in 
the char[] characters is : "i l v _ o e t f s". (desired output from the program)

I've already tried using this code, but still, 
keep getting error at **`characters[i] = num1`**;

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What's the error?  Is it ArgumentOutOfRange?

Comment: IndexOutOfTheRangeException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the error you get is `IndexOutOfRangeException` this is because of the `i = i + 2;`.  The `while` makes sure that `i` is less than `length`, but then adding 2 could result in it being more.  Just add a check that it isn't beyond the `length`.

```
i = i + 2; 
if(i < length)
    characters[i] = num1;
```

Or just change to a `for` loop.

```
Random randem = new Random();
char[] characters = input.ToCharArray();
for(int i = 1; i < length; i += 2)
{
    int num = randem.Next(1, 10); // max value is exclusive
    char num1 = num.ToString()[0];
    characters[i] = num1;
}
output = new string(characters);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Also as Shar1er80 points out you're currently converting the digit to the `char` that has the same ASCII value, and not the the actual characters that represent the digit.  The digits 0-9 are represented by the the values 48-57.  You can change the call to `Random.Next` to be:

```
int num = randem.Next(48, 58); // The upper bound is exclusive, not inclusive
char num1 = (char)num;
```

Or as Shar1er80 does it

```
int num = randem.Next(0,10) // Assumming you want digits 0-9
char num1 = num.ToString[0];
```

Also note that the max value for `Random.Next` is exclusive, so if you want to include the possibility of using a 9 you have to use an upper bound that is 1 greater than the greatest value you want.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you reach `i = 17` you add 2 to `i`  . That makes `i = 19` with length of input equal to 18 that causes out of range exception.

Answer (score 1):

its because you start at index -1, and characters doesn't contain an index of -1.

EDIT: Sorry no the corrct answer is it must be  `while(i < length - 2)`

Comment: But in the loop the OP does `i = i + 2;`, so the first index hit will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is `IndexOutOfTheRangeException`, which explains everthing in itself.

It means that index you are feeding to array in the loop is going beyond its `length-1` (as arrays have 0-based indexing)

So when you do `i+2`, you need to check if `i+2` is not exceeding `i.length-1` at any point of time; which does in your loop.

In general just check if you are supplying indexes between `0 and Array.Length-1`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
char num1 = Convert.ToChar(num);
```

To

```
char num1 = num.ToString()[0];
```

Then... Put

```
characters[i] = num1;
```

In an if block

```
if (i < length)
    characters[i] = num1;
```